# How to send email using google server in my site

Tags: php, gmail

Now we are using our own server to send email to our customers. its possible to send email using google server. how to do this. explain with php codes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download PHPMailer from http://phpmailer.sourceforge.net
Extract to folder phpmailer
Create a file email.php
Paste this code and change the values in blue as you need (I modified the sample code given on the PHPMailer homepage)

```
<?php
    require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = "username@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password
    $webmaster_email = "username@doamin.com"; //Reply to this email ID
    $email="username@domain.com"; // Recipients email ID
    $name="name"; // Recipient's name
    $mail->From = $webmaster_email;
    $mail->FromName = "Webmaster";
    $mail->AddAddress($email,$name);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email,"Webmaster");
    $mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap
    $mail->AddAttachment("/var/tmp/file.tar.gz"); // attachment
    $mail->AddAttachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg"); // attachment
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
    $mail->Subject = "This is the subject";
    $mail->Body = "Hi,
    This is the HTML BODY "; //HTML Body
    $mail->AltBody = "This is the body when user views in plain text format"; //Text Body
    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Message has been sent";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: where i need to place email.php file

Comment: Call to undefined function IsSMTP() in PHPMailer/email.php on line 5    Error Comes for me

Comment: Put it in the directory above the /phpmailer/ directory

Comment: Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. This error comes for me. Did i need to change port number in class.smtp.php

Comment: I'm assuming you have replaced things like 'username@gmail.com'with your own gmail email address and password?

Comment: Open the file class.smtp.php in phpmailer directory
Change the following lines:
$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = 465;

Comment: How to send to more than one. i need to send multiple email id

Comment: Original line 5, which @MohanRam mentions above -- `IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP` -- looks like a cut-and-paste error so I've removed it.

Answer (score 2):

```
function email($to, $subject, $body){
    require_once("class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Username = "email@domain.com";
    $mail->Password = "password";

    $mail->SetFrom("anything@domain.com", "Any Thing"); 

    if(is_array($to)){
        foreach($to as $t){
            $mail->AddAddress($t);                   
        }
    }else{
        $mail->AddAddress($to);
    }

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;


    $mail->Send();
    unset($mail);
}
```

Download http://phpmailer.sourceforge.net/ and name it "class.phpmailer.php"

Comment: How to send to more than one. i need to send multiple email id

Comment: I edited my function, should work now, just pass $to as array of addresses like $to = array("you@you.com", "me@me.com", ... )

Answer (score 0):

http://micrub.info/2008/09/22/sending-email-with-zend_mail-using-gmail-smtp-services/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079/php-mail-using-gmail