# what is the best way for sending E-mails using php and gmail?

Tags: php, email, gmail

what is the best way for sending E-mails using php and gmail ?

i found th below link :

[sending mail with PHPMailer](http://deepakssn.blogspot.com/2006/06/gmail-php-send-email-using-php-with.html)

but after download PHPMailer form it's site , i could n't find class.phpmailer.php !

would u plz show me a way for sending mail (gmail server and php lan)?

another question is my gmail account has set on smtp / is it ok?

best regards

Comment: can u show me a full code without using phpmailer with all features such as ssl / port / html body ...

Comment: May want to checkout a similar SO question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079/php-mail-using-gmail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) with its SmtpTransport, where you specify smtp.gmail.com as SMTP server and specify it to use SSL.

[Example](http://www.swiftmailer.org/wikidocs/v3/connections/smtp):

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com')
    ->setPort(465)
    ->setEncryption('ssl')
    ->setUsername('yourname@gmail.com')
    ->setPassword('YOUR_SECRET_PWD');
...
```

Edit,
as requested - here's a full example (untested though):

```
<?php
require_once "lib/swift_required.php";

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com')
    ->setPort(465)
    ->setEncryption('ssl')
    ->setUsername('yourname@gmail.com')
    ->setPassword('YOUR_SECRET_PWD');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$htmlBody = '<html><body><h1>HTML-mail example!</h1><p>Contents</p></body></html>';
$plainBody = 'Looks like you cannot read HTML-emails? This is alternative content only for you.';

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('This is the subject of the e-mail')
    ->setFrom(array('yourname@gmail.com' => 'You Name'))
    ->setTo(array('yourfriend@domain.com' => 'Your Friends Name'))
    ->setBody($plainBody)
    ->addPart($htmlBody, 'text/html');

$mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: woul u plz learn me phpmailer or easier way! / because i want to test it in a free host and it seems SwiftMailer size is high...

Comment: there is no documentation in phpmailer site / why? how can i use it's project?

Comment: i just want send mail (with gmail)/ would u plz write for me a complete code for doing that ?

Comment: Here are the PHPMailer examples http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examples

Comment: i read the exampls / but after download the phpmailer there is no class.phpmailer.php file!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!where is that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is Zend Framework included on your free host?

So you could use Zend Mail:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.mail.introduction.html