# how i send form value to mail in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send mail using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634029/how-to-send-mail-using-php)
>   [php mail cannot be sent with smtp.gmail.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331006/php-mail-cannot-be-sent-with-smtp-gmail-com)

I'm having some problems sending mail in PHP using the `mail()` function.
here is my php code

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
  {
  //send email
  ini_set("SMTP", "ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
  mail("mr.choudhary_2008@rediff.com",$subject,$message,"From:" .$email);
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
  }
else
//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
  {
  echo "<form method='post' action='email.php'>
  Email: <input name='email' type='text' /><br />
  Subject: <input name='subject' type='text' /><br />
  Message:<br />
  <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
  </textarea><br />
  <input type='submit' />
  </form>";
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in D:\xampp\htdocs\email.php on line 14

Thank you for using our mail form
```

Comment: Are you sure that's `ini_set("SMTP", "ssl://smtp.gmail.com");` enough data to send email through Google server ? Why do you need this?

Comment: @koushal, check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page

Comment: You are missing $port = "465";

you can find more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page

Comment: gmail smtp requires username and password.. You should provide them

Comment: better to use phpmailer ( www.phpmailer.worxware.com/ )

Comment: It's better to use PHPMailer class or something

Answer (score 0):

Check `/usr/sbin/sendmail` and `/usr/lib/sendmail` first. Make sure you have send mail basic.

Answer (score 0):

The mail settings are wrong. Use these settings.

```
smtp.auth=true
smtp.ssl=true
smtp.tls=true
smtp.username=unm
smtp.password=pwd
smtp.server="smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.port="465"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
ini_set( SMTP, "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" ); 
ini_set( smtp_port, 425 );
ini_set("username","<youremail>");  
ini_set("password","<yourpassword>");
```